# How to Add action event work when click on customize list cell button in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Create a Table View.
then create a customize table View cell and place a button on cell and Now I try to get Table View index when click on index.
But when I click on button that place on cell It's not giving me the Index of list.

My Table View class name is `SubMenuViewController` and cell class name is `SubMenuCell`
and my code of `SubMenuViewController` is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
ModelLocator *model = [ModelLocator getInstance];
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SubMenuCell";

    SubMenuCell *cell = (SubMenuCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SubMenuCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    if (model.foodSubItemList) {
        FoodSubItemVO* foodSubItemTemp = [model.foodSubItemList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [cell.lbSubFoodItem setText: foodSubItemTemp.foodSubItemName];
        [cell.lbPrice setText: foodSubItemTemp.price];
        [cell setIndexPath:indexPath];
     }
return cell;
}
```

and My SubMenuCell code here

```
- (IBAction)addItemIntoOrder:(id)sender {
        NSLog(@"@%",indexPath);
        NSLog(@"@%",indexPath.row);
}
```

indexPath declare in SubMenuCell.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your NSLog's are faulty; try this instead (mind that changed % and @ order).

```
- (IBAction)addItemIntoOrder:(id)sender 
{
    NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);
    NSLog(@"%@",indexPath.row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `addItemIntoOrder:` action is hooked up to your delegate correctly in IB.